# How to make complex native splash screen in Flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, splash-screen

Many flutter example shows `launch_backgrond.xml` like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Modify this file to customize your launch splash screen -->
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@color/splash_color" />

    <!-- You can insert your own image assets here -->
    <!-- <item>
        <bitmap
            android:gravity="center"
            android:src="@mipmap/launch_image" />
    </item> -->
    <item>
        <bitmap android:gravity="center" android:src="@drawable/splash" />
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

I need more complex (e.g. fix logo image size depending on device size / use multiple logo images) than this.
I used RelativeLayout or ConstraintLayout but they caused crashes.
How to solve this?

Comment: i dont think so: there is no way to auto resize the layer keeping its aspect ratio, so on devices 18:9 it will be taller than on typical 16:9

Comment: did you figure this out?

Comment: Actually not yet.

Comment: Honeslty it boggles my mind how many "fake" tutorials are out there for creating Splash Screens using Flutter (thus forcing the user to stare at a static blank, black, or whatever the color screen).

The doc in Flutter.dev for Native Splash Screens is terrible... and so far I haven't found a single proper tutorial in how to create a complex native splash for Android and iOS....